# How to apply pixelated effect on imageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am looking reference code for achieving Pixelation effect on android image view.Basically I want to apply different effects on image.I have done some other effects like blurry effect but I am not able to found exact solutions for same.I am looking effect shown on attach image.[image: Pixlated effect]

Comment: please elaborate your problem, so you will get better help from community

Comment: Anyway, this is'n called a pixellated effect (which is SQUARE or RECTANGULAR, not triangular / rhomboidal pixels, aligned in a grid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is filters library for android: [android-image-filter](https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter)

```
BitmapFilter.changeStyle(originBitmap, BitmapFilter.PIXELATE_STYLE, pixelSize);
```

It doesn't produce image like you posted so you will need to do some improvements.